# Deploying .NET Framework 4.5 with Installshield

Tags: entity-framework, installshield

I have written an application that I deploy via Clickonce, but I want to deploy it via Installshield, so I am experimenting with it. I found and downloaded dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.exe, the redistributable for  .NET Framework 4.5,  and made a Installshield prerequisite from it. I wrote a simple application that has a RDLC report that just says “Hello World”, and it needs .NET Framework 4.5, and used Installshield to deploy it. The Reportviewer needs Microsoft SQLClrTypes_x86.msi and SQLClrTypes_x64.msi, and ReportViewer.msi, so I got those and made Installshield prerequisites from them. For the ReportViewer.prq, I specified SQLClrTypes_x86.prq and SQLClrTypes_x64.prq, as dependencies, and for SQLClrTypes_x86.prq and SQLClrTypes_x64.prq I specified  dotnetfx45_full_x86_x64.prq as a dependency.

When I installed my little application on my test computer (running Windows 7), it installed the 4.5 framework, said it needed to reboot, and asked if I wanted to reboot now,  and I clicked Yes. I was thinking it would reboot and continue the installation, but when it rebooted, that was the end of the installation. I ran setup again, it asked if I wanted to install the 4.5 Framework (it asked me the first time, too), so I clicked No. After clicking No, it installed the rest of my program, and it ran perfectly.

How can I get the installation to continue after it reboots from installing the .NET Framework 4.5?

Thanks

Comment: What version and edition of InstallShield are you using?

Comment: I am using IS 2010 Premier with Virtualization , version 16

Answer (score 1):

Here's a blog I wrote about 9 years ago:

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.iswix.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)

It hasn't changed much.   You want to use the prereq editor to change the reboot behavior to **Note it, fail to resume if the machine is rebooted, and reboot after the installation**.

Also please note that InstallShield consumes it's PRQ files from the ISProductFolder (C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield.... )   I don't care for this from a CM perspective.  I recommend isolating the file and file references to relative paths based on ISProjectFolder and keeping all of these files in your source control tool.

[Behavior Tab](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield18helplib/UIRefPrereqEditor_Behavior.htm)