# how to add an installtion of .NET Framework in installshield Project

Tags: visual-studio, installation, installshield

I am creating an installtion project on visual studio using installshield express.

I want to create an installtion that if the user will not have .Net Framework version 4.5.1

the installtion will install it for him.
if I marked on installtion requirements that .NET Framework it will only pop up a message that the user need to install and will not install it for him.

how can I do that?

P.S

Comment: @ ברק רוזנפלד , what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue in your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried below things which worked for me to install .NET framework automatically if not installed on the client machine.
In the InstallShield you can refer to Redistributables tab. In this tab there are multiple Redistributables listed. We can select which one we need for our project. And after checking the right Redistributable, make sure the location of Redistributable is Installed locally. And right click the Redistributable and select Build Location as "Extract From Setup.exe". 
After this when the project is build, InstallShield will add a folder "ISSetupPrerequisites"along with Setup.exe. This folder consists of the required prerequisites setups such as .NET framework 4.0 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to the follow two documents which shared the same issue about how to deploy the .Net framework in your set up project. even if they are related to the different versions(Tools and .NET):

Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0:

http://helpnet.installshield.com/isxhelp21/helplibrary/NetRedistAdd.htm

Deploying .NET Framework 4.5 with Installshield:

[Deploying .NET Framework 4.5 with Installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30157956/deploying-net-framework-4-5-with-installshield)